# Post SWF in user timeline

Tags: facebook, api, iframe, flash

I have a problem in my iframe facebook application, is a music app where the users can post music in a music player, then problem is that when the user share the SWF into the timeline wall the players doesn't appear, it only show the URL to the music file.

I added the server IPs list in the Whitelist app configuration, how can I solve it? :(

Here the code:

```
try {
    $actions  = json_encode(array(array('text'=>facebook_app_post_ok_in_my_profile, 'href'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/fbapp/post_check.php?  where=me&song='.$selected_value.'')));
    $param  =   array(
    'method'        =>  'stream.publish',
    'callback'      =>  '',
    'name'      =>  facebook_app_post_ok_feed_name,
    'href'      =>  'http://www.site.com',
    'description'      =>  facebook_app_post_ok_description,
    'message'       =>  $message_feed,
    'attachment'    =>  '{"media": [{
    "type": "mp3",
    "src":   "'.$real_source.'",
    "title": "'.$song_title.'",
    "artist": "'.$song_artist.'",
    "album": "'.$song_album.'"
    }]}
    ','action_links'  =>  $actions,
    'target_id'     =>  $user_id,
    'privacy'       =>  ''
    );
    $facebook->api($param);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to follow the instructions in [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/). I know it's called Feed Gaming and that's nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve, but the basic premise is the same. You want an interactive `swf` that the user can open in their News Feed.

Once you have you OG markup in place on the end URL, FB will pick all that up and render the `swf`.